# How can I remove a RSS feed that a WordPress plugin adds to `wp_head()`?

Tags: rss

I'm using a plugin that adds an RSS feed to WordPress. I don't want it there.

There is no option in the plugin's settings to disable it.

How can I unhook it from `wp_head()`, *or*, where do you register `head` element things in a WordPress plugin so I can manually remove it?

Thanks

Comment: *@Alex*: It would help it you tell us the name of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Without the specfic plugin name, I can only be fairly vague, but there are two things you can do:

---

To add additional code to unhook `<link />` tag (which is what I presume it's adding) you would use something like:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'name_of_function')
```

You would, however, need to know the name of the function you wished to remove, which makes simply removing the hook easier.

---

To add the `<link>` tag to your wp_head the plugin will probably use code similar to this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'name_of_function')
```

Obviously it is much easier to find if you already know the name of the function which you are trying to remove, but a search for `add_action('wp_head'` or `add_action("wp_head"` should find the line specified, which you can then remove to stop the insertion.

Comment: Damn, I searched for `wp_head` but only found things that seemed unrelated.